# Changing file structure when using git

Tags: git, github

is there any way in which i can change the file structure on visual studio code whenever i create a new branch?

I recently created a new local repository and cloned form my remote repository

Now when i want to create a new branch, the file structure just remains the same. How can i set it so that the file structure is the same for the local main branch and produce a copy of the local files for the feature1 local branch that i make?

Is such a function possible with git? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZRi5.png)

Comment: Hello @Malemna, I'm a little confused with what you're trying to achieve, could you describe the initial and desired file structure? And what exactly do you mean by file structure?

Comment: So for example when i clone from a remote repository i download all the files into my local repository main branch. I then want to create a new branch feature 1 off of my local main and i want there to be a copy of the original files so that i can edit them. Because if i create multiple branch ill maybe have to reclone the remote repository since the initial cloned version have changed in my local directory from edits

Comment: Ah! I think I understand, let me try and answer the question.

Comment: Ok thank you, i just hope i was clear ahha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I understand what you're trying to do. You want to retain your files while you checkout a new branch.

I think you're confused about how exactly `git` works. So basically the local copy that you want to do, is intrinsically handled by git. You don't need to worry about it. When you create a new branch and you make commits there, they only exist in that branch in some sense. You can always go back to your old branch and git will automatically revert the changes to ensure your files were as before.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh okay so youre saying once i make a new branch, edit the files then switch the branch back my file will automatically change?

Comment: That's right! Git handles that stuff. But ensure you create a commit in the new branch before changing back :)

Comment: I can see that that is true, when i switch branches after commits the file structure changes, thank for your help :)